# Parse .conf file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I have a file called **clients.conf** .

Here is its content :

```
client: {
    # client data
    name: "James"
    information: {
        age: "32"
        adress: "258 Arthur Street"    
    }
    email: jamesbryan@yyyy.com
    certification: {
        status: "expired"
        id: 12345324
    }
}
```

I would like to parse it using python 2.7 (or 3.x).
Here is the code I am using, it doesn't detect any section in the file:

```
config = ConfigParser()
with open('clients.conf') as stream:
    stream = StringIO(stream.read())  
    config.readfp(stream)

print(config.sections())
```

The print.sections() at the end provides an empty array.

Comment: why not to use `json`?

Comment: Yeah, `ConfigParser` is meant for INI style files - what you have is nothing like that. Your file has nested blocks and mixed `=`s and `:`s and unquoted string literals and quoted strings and `#` comments..... you'll need to write a parser yourself.

Comment: @DecowVR One good reason might be that the input data is not JSON.

Comment: @AKX `stream.read().replace("\n", ",")` and it will become a json :( (omiting comments)

Comment: @DecowVR No, no it won't.

Comment: My bad, the file doesn't contain any "=", I corrected the question.

Comment: Where did you get this file? Can you also double-check whether the email field is unquoted as in your example..?

Comment: Some fields are quoted and some are not :( All I know is that it is a .conf file.
I am a beginner to using such files

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an HJSON document, you can parse it using the [`hjson`](https://pypi.org/project/hjson/) module.

```
import hjson

with open("client.conf", 'r') as f:
    conf = hjson.load(f)

print(conf["client"]["name"])  # James
print(conf["client"]["email"])  # jamesbryan@yyyy.com
```